# Linux Pybind11 'build check -j 4' error

Tags: c++, python-3.x, c++11, pybind11

After installing Pybind11 for linux, I run the command -

`make check -j 4` as mentioned in the document - http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/master/basics.html

I get the below errors -

make[3]: *** [tests/test_cmake_build/CMakeFiles/test_subdirectory_embed] Error 1
make[2]: *** [tests/test_cmake_build/CMakeFiles/test_subdirectory_embed.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

make[1]: *** [tests/CMakeFiles/check.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [check] Error 2

I am not sure what this means or how to fix it. Any help is appreciated. Below is the complete log list that I get -

```
{
Scanning dependencies of target test_subdirectory_embed
Scanning dependencies of target test_subdirectory_target
Scanning dependencies of target mock_install
Scanning dependencies of target test_subdirectory_function
-- Install configuration: "MinSizeRel"
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/detail
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/detail/internals.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/detail/class.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/detail/typeid.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/detail/descr.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/detail/common.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/detail/init.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/pybind11.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/cast.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/common.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/attr.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/iostream.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/eigen.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/options.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/pytypes.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/stl_bind.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/buffer_info.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/chrono.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/eval.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/stl.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/embed.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/numpy.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/operators.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/functional.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/include/pybind11/complex.h
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/share/cmake/pybind11/pybind11Config.cmake
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/share/cmake/pybind11/pybind11ConfigVersion.cmake
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/share/cmake/pybind11/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/share/cmake/pybind11/pybind11Tools.cmake
-- Installing: /mnt/home/srinivasa/python3_env/pybind11/build/mock_install/share/cmake/pybind11/pybind11Targets.cmake
[  0%] Built target mock_install
Scanning dependencies of target pybind11_tests
[  2%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/pybind11_tests.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_buffers.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_builtin_casters.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_call_policies.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_callbacks.cpp.o
[ 17%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_chrono.cpp.o
[ 17%] Built target test_subdirectory_target
Scanning dependencies of target pybind11_cross_module_tests
[ 20%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_cross_module_tests.dir/pybind11_cross_module_tests.cpp.o
make[3]: *** [tests/test_cmake_build/CMakeFiles/test_subdirectory_embed] Error 1
make[2]: *** [tests/test_cmake_build/CMakeFiles/test_subdirectory_embed.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 22%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_class.cpp.o
[ 22%] Built target test_subdirectory_function
[ 25%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_constants_and_functions.cpp.o
[ 28%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_copy_move.cpp.o
[ 31%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_docstring_options.cpp.o
[ 34%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_enum.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_eval.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_exceptions.cpp.o
[ 42%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_factory_constructors.cpp.o
[ 45%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_iostream.cpp.o
[ 48%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_kwargs_and_defaults.cpp.o
[ 51%] Linking CXX shared module ../../tests/pybind11_cross_module_tests.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
[ 54%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_local_bindings.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_methods_and_attributes.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_modules.cpp.o
[ 60%] Built target pybind11_cross_module_tests
[ 62%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_multiple_inheritance.cpp.o
[ 65%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_numpy_array.cpp.o
[ 68%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_numpy_dtypes.cpp.o
[ 71%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_numpy_vectorize.cpp.o
[ 74%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_opaque_types.cpp.o
[ 77%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_operator_overloading.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_pickling.cpp.o
[ 82%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_pytypes.cpp.o
[ 85%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_sequences_and_iterators.cpp.o
[ 88%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_smart_ptr.cpp.o
[ 91%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_stl.cpp.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_stl_binders.cpp.o
[ 97%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/pybind11_tests.dir/test_virtual_functions.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared module ../../tests/pybind11_tests.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
------ pybind11_tests.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so file size: 1807600
[100%] Built target pybind11_tests
make[1]: *** [tests/CMakeFiles/check.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [check] Error 2
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find an explanation about this?

Answer (score 2):

Same problem on CentOS7, the same processure works fine on MAC OS.

follow the guide on https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1628

and compile with `make -j4 pytest`, it works.